# json_encode missing part of row containing a date

Tags: php, json

**Code**

```
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(

    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'date'),
    array('label' => 'Orders', 'type' => 'number')

);

    $rows = array();
    while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) {

        $temp = array();

        $temp[] = array('h' => (int) $row['Date']);
        $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $row['Orders']);
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);

    }

    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

### Update

Thanks to WereWolf - The Alpha for the answer, it is using the complete date but now I have some weird problem with \ and / as below.

```
{
   "cols":[
      {
         "label":"Date",
         "type":"date"
      },
      {
         "label":"Orders",
         "type":"number"
      }
   ],
   "rows":[
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "h":"2014\/05\/02 00:00"
            },
            {
               "v":8
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "h":"2014\/05\/06 00:00"
            },
            {
               "v":10
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "h":"2014\/05\/07 00:00"
            },
            {
               "v":9
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "c":[
            {
               "h":"2014\/05\/08 00:00"
            },
            {
               "v":10
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have used following code:

```
$temp[] = array('h' => (int) $row['Date']);
```

Remove the `(int)`:

```
$temp[] = array('h' => $row['Date']);
```

For example, try this:

```
$d = '2014/05/08 00:00';
echo $d; // 2014/05/08 00:00
```

Now try this:

```
$d = '2014/05/08 00:00';
$d = (int) $d;
echo $d; // 2014
```

Becaue `(int)` is parsing the integer from the string `'2014/05/08 00:00'` so it's just excluding everything from `/05/08 00:00'` because `/` it's not `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I completely missed that `(int)`, but now I have some weird problem with \ and /, can you see?

Comment: Got it, those are escaped, not a problem at all

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

For more info and other flags please see [Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Also remove `(int)` cast to date .

Comment: I tried that but it didn't make a difference, output is still showing the year only i.e. `{"cols":[{"label":"Date","type":"date"},{"label":"Orders","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"h":2014},{"v":8}]},{"c":[{"h":2014},{"v":10}]},{"c":[{"h":2014},{"v":9}]},{"c":[{"h":2014},{"v":10}]}]}`.